# GitHub: intra-repo permissions

Tags: github, github-actions

When working with GitHub private repos it is often the case that something need to be shared between them from within a Workflow. Specifically, assume I have two private repos, `RepoA` and `RepoB`, both within the same organization.

How can I allow RepoA to ...

- (1) Use GitHub Shared Workflows located in RepoB?
  (Recipe: In RepoB, go to Settings --> Actions --> General --> section named "Access")
- (2) Download/consume Packages produced by RepoB?
  (Recipe: In RepoB, from the front page: click the name of the package you want to share, then click "Package Settings". In the section called "Manage Actions access", you must then explicitly select the repos that are allowed to consume the package. Add RepoA to this list.)
- (3) Download Release artifacts produced by RepoB?
- (4) Clone RepoB?

Specifically (3) and (4) are my concrete questions which I don't know how to do. The (1) and (2) exists purely for reference so that hopefully people can see what I'm hinting at. I've listed the recipe for the solution for (1) and (2) to make it clearer the kind of answer I'm looking for.

I'm looking for a solution (like (1) and (2)) that doesn't rely on PATs, but instead uses the `GITHUB_TOKEN`. It is my impression that PATs should not be used for intra-repo access, they are meant for *personal* access.

Comment: Are those private repos from a personal account, or from a team / org account? Depending on the account type, you might have to use PAT to access items from private repositories.

Comment: @GuiFalourd. Org account. (Enterprise Plan)

Comment: In that case, you probably won't need a PAT, just the Github Token [enabling permissions (ref)](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token) to access packages, other repository-projects, etc... in the workflow should resolve your issue. The [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout#Checkout-multiple-repos-private) can also helps you clone private repo with this token.

Comment: @GuiFalourd. I'm afraid I cannot follow you. The link you supply have to do with the token's permissions in _own_ repo, not in another repo.

Comment: According to the link I shared, you can update the `GITHUB_TOKEN` default permissions for your enterprise, organization, or repository. I understand that in your case, it could be at the Org level.

Comment: @GuiFalourd: You mistunderstand GitHub's documentation: Yes, you can set those default permissions for the `GITHUB_TOKEN` and you can set them at the org-level. But they are still only concerned with own repo. So, as an example: `contents: read` means the token can read its own repo (e.g. clone it). Setting for example default setting at org-level `contents: write` would mean that by default all tokens can even write to their own repo (e.g perform push).

Comment: Understood. In that case, you will only be able to perform operations cross repositories with a PAT, as stated [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#granting-additional-permissions).

Comment: @GuiFalourd: My point is that some operations are indeed possible cross-repo with `GITHUB_TOKEN`. Those are the ones (1) and (2) in my question. They are well-hidden in GitHub docs and I stumbled upon them. There might be hidden feature for (3) and (4) as well? My impression is that GitHub is scrambling to add cross-repo features to `GITHUB_TOKEN` and that the official docs do not always follow suit. You can find places in the GitHub documentation that leaves you with the impression that (1) and (2) requires a PAT, while that is indeed no longer true.

Comment: According to what is specified in this action [here](https://github.com/dawidd6/action-download-artifact): You may use a _GitHub token in a job where the permissions `action` scope set to `read`_, to download artifacts from private repositories (I've never done it in an organization to know if it indeed works). Regarding cloning a private repo, based on the researches and tests I've done, it doesn't seem possible only with the Github token.

Comment: I'd say you're mostly right that they are adhoc implementing cross-repo features to the `GITHUB_TOKEN` -- the implementations for `1` and `2` are _relatively_ recent. I can't see anything related to `3` or `4` in the [public backlog](https://github.com/orgs/github/projects/4247/views/11) -- and I'm not personally a fan of PATs, but their use in workflows to get around not having an ephemeral key for other repos or those permissions grantable to the `GITHUB_TOKEN` is pretty well established. If you scope them appropriately and trust people in your org to not misuse them they should be fine.

Comment: @Skenvy. Thanks. I'm also skeptical about PATs.  Probably more than you. For example, what happens if the user who owns the PAT, is no longer part of the org? (i.e. he gets fired, he changes job to work for another company, etc). Either the PAT will continue to work (which is inherently wrong!) or it doesn't and your previously well-functioning pipelines will suddenly break down .. and I bet nobody will (at the time) be able to figure out why. Either way it is bad. So, no, PATs should not be used in a pipeline, I think.

Comment: If it's same organization, can't you just change those repos from private to internal?

Comment: @Moro internal repos are an Enterprise feature.

Comment: @peterh
> For example, what happens if the user who owns the PAT, is no longer part of the org?

They will stop working. PATs have a scope of the user. What we did is create a dedicated account for such PATs. And wait until GitHub gets their sh** together.